# What sort of skills do I need to become a Substrate runtime engineer?

Tags: learning, general

I'm looking to take some courses in order to learn how to become a Substrate runtime engineer. What skills do I need and how can I continue improving them as I progress?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're aiming to become a Substrate runtime engineer, you'll need to know:

- What blockchains are and how they work. A good course on this is the [MOOC](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxVihxZC42nF_MCN9PTvZMIifRjx9cZ2J) by the Web3 Foundation.
- Crypto-economics and game theory — at least enough to help you design or understand the applications you're working on.
- Rust. You'll need to learn [how to understand and write Rust code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/), there's no work around this. [This](https://rustinblockchain.org/learning/) page has a good variety of resources for learning Rust in the field of blockchain technology.
- What the relay chain / parachain model is and how it works. The best place is the [Polkadot docs](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/getting-started).

The best way to continue improving is by writing your own runtime logic, reviewing PRs and trying new things!

Comment: I would add that you need a very firm grasp on rust traits and generics in particular.

Answer (score 2):

As a quick update, the basics are also incredibly important! The [Web3 Foundation has launched educational courses with EdX](https://medium.com/web3foundation/polkadot-web3-educational-courses-launching-on-edx-9a67f4f6f731) (the same platform used by MIT, Harvard, Berkley University of California, Boston University).

The courses will start on Oct 27, and will be archived for your benefit:

- [Introduction to Polkadot](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-to-polkadot)
- [Introduction to Blockchain and Web3](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-to-blockchain-and-web3)