# What is the most straight forward/complete project i can work to master substrate?

Tags: polkadot, parachain

Basically a project that would relay on all the nuts and bolts in the substrate toolset to understand more of where the ecosystem is going and how to work for companies like parity tech.

Comment: This is similar to https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/962/what-sort-of-skills-do-i-need-to-become-a-substrate-runtime-engineer

Answer (score 5):

You could start by going through all the tutorials here: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3

Be on the lookout for an upcoming hackathon: https://substrate.io/ecosystem/opportunities/hackathons

If you're looking for a real-world application, then pick a topic that you like and build a Substrate chain. For example, if you're into NFTs, build a Substrate NFT chain. This will require you to put together a runtime with FRAME pallets and learn how to run a Substrate node among various other topics.

You could take that a step further and convert it into a parachain.

If you reach that milestone, then deploy on the Rococo testnet, do a couple runtime upgrades to understand how that works and try opening HRMP channels with other parachains.

By doing all of this you will become familiar with how Substrate/Polkadot works and you will touch on key Substrate features.